# Whenever compile, I keep getting the error that it cannot find the symbol

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextarea, joptionpane

I'm new to JTextArea and JScrollPane, whenever I compile I get this error, Project3.java:95: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Dimension
location: class Project3
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));

Can someone please help me?

```
    JTextArea listBox = new JTextArea(input);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(listBox);  
    listBox.setLineWrap(true);  
    listBox.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scroll, "Dictionary enteries" JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

   return aLineFromFile;
```

This is the full method.

```
 public static String listDictionary()throws IOException
{
   String input = "";
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
   String aLineFromFile = null;

   while((aLineFromFile = br.readLine()) != null)
   {
        input += aLineFromFile + "\n";
   }
   br.close();
    JTextArea listBox = new JTextArea(input);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(listBox);  
    listBox.setLineWrap(true);  
    listBox.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scroll, "Dictionary enteries", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

   return aLineFromFile;
}
```

I have imported, import java.io.*; import javax.swing.*; import java.util.*;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimension is in [java.awt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/class-use/Dimension.html), so add `import java.awt.Dimension;`

I would suggest using Eclipse or Netbeans. They will tell you that you need to add imports like this.